# AzureRM Automation DSC Configuration

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure, dsc

I'm trying to configure Azure DSC Configuration, but I am running into two issues.

1. I continue to get this error message

- Error = 'invalid character 'c' looking for beginning of value' JSON = 'configuration cdavdtest {}'*
  *2. No matter what I do to the resource azurerm_automation_dsc_configuration , it throws this command which is a reference to my last terraform plan / apply that failed. Changing the configuration does nothing, and the old error continues. I appreciate any help. See the cdavdtest in bold compared to the resource also in bold below.  Also the name doesn't update it still says dsc_config even though I updated it to dsc_configa.

Error: making Read request on AzureRM Automation Dsc Configuration content "cdavdtest": automation.DscConfigurationClient#GetContent: Failure responding to request: StatusCode=200 -- Original Error: Error occurred unmarshalling
JSON - Error = 'invalid character 'c' looking for beginning of value' JSON = 'configuration **cdavdtest** {}'
│
│   with azurerm_automation_dsc_configuration.dsc_config,
│   on automationaccount.tf line 17, in resource "azurerm_automation_dsc_configuration" "dsc_config":
│   17: resource azurerm_automation_dsc_configuration dsc_config {

```
resource azurerm_automation_account automation_account {
    name = "${var.avd.name}-automationaccount"
    location = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
    resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
    sku_name = "Basic"
}

output "end_point" {
    value = azurerm_automation_account.automation_account.dsc_server_endpoint
}

output registration_key {
    value = azurerm_automation_account.automation_account.dsc_primary_access_key
}


resource azurerm_automation_dsc_configuration dsc_configa {
    name = "**test**"
    location = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
    resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name 
    automation_account_name = azurerm_automation_account.automation_account.name
    description = "Configuration node for Azure Virtual Desktop"
    content_embedded = "Configuration **test** {}"
    log_verbose = true
}
```

I have tried commenting out the code and I still get the error. I've tried updating the name. I've tried using the <<BODY and writing out the configuration but this still persists.

Comment: Hi there, it looks to be complaining about a different resource `"azurerm_automation_dsc_configuration" "dsc_config"`. Is your example is `dsc_configa` a direct representation of `dsc_config` or does your code have both resources? Cheers

Comment: **Kindly verify the answer if it has rectified your issue. This verification would help the other community members**

Answer (score 0):

***Tested in my Environment was getting the same error. The error is due to*** **[*azurerm_automation_dsc_configuration is broken since provider version 2.96.0*](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/16103)**

I was using the lasted terraform provider version ie `3.0.1`

[image]

[image]

**Solution** : Would Suggest you to please use the provider version between `version = ">=2.10,<=2.30"`

**Terraform Code**

*main.tf file*

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = ">=2.10,<=2.30"
    }
  }
}

provider "azurerm" {
  features{}
  
}


data "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "XXXXXXxXXX"
}

resource "azurerm_automation_account" "example" {
  name                = "account1"
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  sku_name = "Basic"
}


output "end_point" {
    value = azurerm_automation_account.example.dsc_server_endpoint
}

output "registration_key" {
    value = azurerm_automation_account.example.dsc_primary_access_key
}

resource "azurerm_automation_dsc_configuration" "example" {
  name                    = "test"
  resource_group_name     = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  automation_account_name = azurerm_automation_account.example.name
  location                = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  content_embedded        = "configuration test {}"
  log_verbose = true

  
}
```

**OutPut--**

[image]

---

[image]